# How to make the jQuery popup dialog box pop up on "login link" clicks

Tags: jquery

I am working on this site: http://www.problemio.com and I would like the login dialog popup box to pop up whenever the user clicks on the "log in" link.   These links appear throughout the site like on the top-right of the home page, and also on pages the user can not access without being logged in like their home page: http://www.problemio.com/account/member_home.php

Right now I am able to get the dialog box to pop up using jQuery when users submit forms and are not logged-in, like in this form: http://www.problemio.com/add_problem.php  (has to have some input in there).

But how do people get the popup to pop-up on clicks of specific regular links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing that is to include the login form on every page, then use CSS and jQuery to hide it until it's needed, and link up the `click` event of the login link to displaying the form. The form itself can handle posting data to the login page.

[Here's a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/pyNJ9/)

Comment: good example Bryan, exactly how I would've recommended doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code (see note below), it appears that your login links have `class="login_link"` and your login popup launch code is `$("#loginpopup").dialog();`.  To make that popup open when the links are clicked, you need:

```
$('a.login_link').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#loginpopup").dialog();
});
```

References for learning: [jQuery Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), [jQuery .click() method](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

**FYI:** *It would be helpful to actually include an example of the relevant code in your question (*`a.login_link` *and* `$("#loginpopup").dialog();` *in this specific example).  Otherwise, your question essentially has no value to other people browsing StackOverflow looking for answers.*

**FYI 2:** You have tons of lines commented out with `//` comments.  You can use `/*my comment*/` for multiline comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, its a tutorial i wrote on how to create this login and signup form when clicked on a link or a button. No need to use jQuery UI for this, just simple jQuery popup plugin and HTML CSS. http://www.andwecode.com/create-popup-login-and-signup-form/